# Receive information with time zone information, create NSDate without time zone information

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I have a server that sends dates to iOS app in the following format: `2015-05-05T10:40:16+06:00`.

This is the code for `NSDateFormatter` I use:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-05-05T10:40:16+06:00";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

My problem is that because of our business requirements iOS app is forced to always use local time without time zone information (i.e. local time stored in NSDate) so the above code produces output which is correct behavior of NSDateFormatter but is not appropriate for my use case:

```
date: 2015-05-05 04:40:16 +0000
```

Is there a way to have NSDate without time zone subtraction like:

```
date: 2015-05-05 10:40:16 +0000
```

so that the NSDate numbers exactly correspond to the numbers of original date string?

I know that if date string doesn't have time zone postfix: `+02:00` I get correct date with 10 hours so currently I assume that I should use regular expression to strip this time zone postfix to make NSDateFormatter not take time zone information into account.

This is the test I want to be passing:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-05-05T10:40:16+06:00";
NSDate *date = [subject dateFromString:dateString]; // what code should be here?

NSLog(@"date %@", date); // date 2015-05-05 04:40:16 +0000
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:DateComponents
                                                           fromDate:date];
components.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
components.hour should equal(10); // Expected 4 to equal 10
```

Comment: The first thing coming to my mind is to use 'timeIntervalSince1970' in projects like yours where you show the users the time in their local timezone. However, it requires you to change your server behaviour a bit so that it will send the number of seconds since 1970, and then to use the related methods in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That was also my idea, but in my case it is not possible to change the server's behavior since it has other non-mobile clients already.